# VB.NET connection string for client-server application

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, connection-string

**Case :**

I'm creating a desktop application with VB.NET (Windows Forms), and using SQL Server 2008 Express for its database.

**Problem :**

I want to create a client-server application, it means I just need 1 database on the server.

I have a computer and a laptop. I set my laptop's IP to `192.168.1.1` and my computer's IP to `192.168.1.2`.

Now I place the database on my computer, the database name is `db_transportasi`.

Problem is, how to connect my computer's database from my laptop?

**Specification :**

I'm using this string below for my connection :

```
Data Source=ARVID-THEODORUS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_TRANSPORTASI;Integrated Security=True
```

I already setup my SQL Configuration Manager, enabled the TCP/IP, switch to the `IP Addresses` tab and set the IPAII Port Properties to 2301

I turned off my firewall so I don't have to set any exception.

Here is the SQL Server SS :

[image: SQL Server First Connect]

**Question :**

1. How to connect to my computer's database from my laptop?
2. Could you show me the example for my laptop VB.NET Connection String?

Thanks before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this link:
http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/

connection string:

```
"Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433;" & _
"Initial Catalog=mySQLServerDBName; User ID=myUsername;" & _
"Password=myPassword"
```

Comment: Thanks, i just need one step ahead. Create a user in sqlserver 2008 and grant control

Answer (score 3):

There you go:

```
"Server=192.168.1.2,1433;Initial Catalog=DB_TRANSPORTASI;Integrated Security=True"
```

[ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) is a good resource for connection strings for many different databases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this page.   A whole list of different ways.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you start up the "SQL Server Browser" service in SQL server configuration manager.